# How can I select element base on string() in Xpath?

Tags: xpath

I have an XML like that:

```html
<tr class="TREven">
<td class="Col0">
<span>
<b>Diary Compliance:</b>
 Number of Daily Reports completed
<br/>
<i>
* Must be 
<u>24</u>
 or more
</i>
</span>
</td>
<td class="Col1">
<span class="Red">4 - Not eligible</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

I don't know how to select "4 - Not eligible" base on my input text (Diary Compliance: Number of Daily Reports completed * Must be 24 or more) which is contained by many child nodes of span before.

Could you help me?

Thanks,

Comment: `//span[@class='Red']/text()`

Comment: no, I need " how to select "4 - Not eligible" base on my input text (Diary Compliance: Number of Daily Reports completed * Must be 24 or more) which is contained by many child nodes of span before."

Answer (score 0):

This is alse my trouble
I often use this xpath to get element on cell 2 base on element on cell 1 in a row table like him: 
//span[contains(text(),'Diary Compliance: Number of Daily Reports completed * Must be 24 or more')]/../..//span[contains(text(),'4 - Not eligible')]

It's ok until I get trouble when element on cell 1 has lot of format node, I can't pass my  exactly text to element on cell 1. In my case, I must use exactly text, not contains text.